# I can't figure out how to execute multiple querys in the same program

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This is for a class, I need to return the table names and the column names of those tables.  I don't have much experience with SQL and I'm trying to do it algorithmic through my program.
The error that's being thrown out is: java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set

```
import java.sql.*;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] tableAry = new String[8];
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees",
            "user1",
            "Password#1");


            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables "
                    + "WHERE table_schema ='employees';");

            //gets table names and puts them in an arry
            while(rs.next()) { 
            tableAry[i]=rs.getString(1);
            i++;
            }


            Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs1;

            //executes a query for column names using said table names
            System.out.println("Loop Start");
            for (int j=0; j<= tableAry.length; j++)
            {
                rs1=stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'" + tableAry[j] + "';");
                System.out.println(tableAry[j]+rs.getString(1));
            }

            con.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

    }

}
```

Comment: an approach i often use is to print the generated sql to standard output then if you cant see a format error in the sql then  run that sql as a native query where  you will get more informative errors from the database(mysql here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will go through your entire result set `rs`

```
while(rs.next()) { 
   tableAry[i]=rs.getString(1);
   i++;
}
```

So when you call

```
System.out.println(tableAry[j]+rs.getString(1));
```

`rs` will point to the end of your result set.

So I'm assuming what you really want to do is:

```
System.out.println(tableAry[j]+rs1.getString(1));
```

maybe?

Comment: Probably, let me get this working on my computer again

Comment: It created new problems, but I know where to go from now,  thanks